# Antd and React Suite Sliders show up "invisible", but are still there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net-core

## Objective

I simply want to display a slider below a color wheel in a component, but the slider only partially shows up. I'm using the Antd React.js package for the slider, and have also encountered the same problem within the React Suite package. This leads me to believe there is something fundamentally wrong about the way I'm approaching this. **Please note that** I'm using React.js on a .NET Core framework (5.0).

## Ant Design Example

I'm trying to follow the example as shown below from the Ant Design slider page.

[image]

## My Implementation

My render code is as follows:

```js
  render() {
      return (
    <div>   
        <ColorPicker onInput={hue => console.log("Selected Hue: " + hue)} />         
        <Slider defaultValue={50} tooltipVisible />  
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.turnOnLight}>Turn on Light</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

## Output

The following pictures show what I see on my page when it renders.

[image]

Furthermore, when I highlight the area where the slider should be, I can see it and change the values displayed on the tooltip.

[image]

## The Issue

I suspect it's a CSS styling issue, since the bar actually shows up. But it's weird. The same exact situation occurs for the React Suite library... So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. Any resources or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Also, please let me know if there is any other code that needs to be posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer as I went to click the post button. I wasn't including the .css stylesheets provided by either Ant design or React Suite. In my imports, I only had

```js
import { Slider } from 'antd';
```

When I should've also added the css import, as follows

```js
import { Slider } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Posting for future reference.